# consulta de datas datepicker

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

boa tarde galera. Como faço  para exibir os dados do banco de dados através da data selecionada no  datepicker? Como o select deve ser utilizado neste caso? já que é o usuário quem vai escolher a data para ser exibida os dados.

Comment: Falta informações, vamos lá: o DataPicker que você se refere é o do Jquery? Que tipo de dado você quer exibir todas as tabelas, ou só uma? Você trabalha com Ajax? Que tipo de conexão você usaria para conectar com o banco? O que você já tem feito?

Comment: opaa, vamos lá então. Sim, é o do jquery, sobre os dados quero exibir todos, não estou trabalhando com ajax, utilzo php pdo como conexão com o banco de dados. Já tenho tudo praticamente feito, falta apenas esta questão de mostrar os dados conforme a data selecionada, estou utilizando o SELECT da seguinte forma:

Comment: ´<?php 
    $pdo_statement = $pdo_conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE data >= cast((now()) as date) and data < cast((now() + interval 1 day) as date) ORDER BY data ASC;");
    $pdo_statement->execute();
    $result = $pdo_statement->fetchAll();
    ?>
    ´

Comment: Adicione o código a pergunta

Comment: neste select eu consigo mostrar os dados cadastrados somente no dia, a dúvida é: como faço para apresentar os dados cadastrados se o usuário selecionar o dia 09/03/2018 (por exemplo) no datepicker

Comment: O problema é como mostrar o resultado na Interface Gráfica? 
Ou como recuperar isso do banco de dados?
Ou como capturar o valor do datapicker e transmitir para o PHP?

Comment: o problema está em recuperar os dados do banco conforme a data selecionada e assim mostrá-lo na tela para o usuário

Comment: Agora sim ficou bem mais claro.

Comment: ?????????????????????????????????????/

Answer (score 0):

Eu faria um `SELECT` assim para campos com coluna date ou datetime:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE DATE_FORMAT(coluna_data, '%d/%m/%Y') = $data
```

`DATE_FORMAT` para formatar no mesmo padrão que vem do JQuery e `$data` é o que o usuário enviou de uma olhada [aqui](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_date_format.asp) para ver mais formatos de datas